# Merge Dll to Assembly or Embed in Resource - which is Better?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll, ilmerge

Should I merge the referenced Dlls into the assembly using `ILMerge` or embed the Dll into the Resource of the Main Assembly and Load at Run-time.

Which would be better in terms of performance.In both cases the Final Executable will be compressed and unpacked at run-time.

Comment: Try both and measure. If you think either is too hard to even try - here is your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not embed the dll in the assembly. This creates an executable assembly that is hard to work with without recompilation and is bulky. It is much better to reference the dlls locally, and that speeds up the program.

Answer (score 0):

This is .NET.  The "executables" are still just bytecode anyway and the actual native code is hidden away in a temporary folder after the runtime JITs it.  I doubt you'll gain any noticeable difference from either of the two proposed methods over the other.

Distributing separate DLLs is nice when you want to make changes to the application, since you're only replacing components, rather than the entire assembly.